# Finding percentiles of the $\chi^2$ distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, chi-squared, percentile

> If the random variable $Y$ has a $\chi^2$ distribution with $54$ degrees of freedom, then what is the approximate $84^{\text{th}}$ percentile of $Y$?

I don't understand very good question when it is with $30$ or more degrees of freedom  and with approximate percentile.

**Please give some explanation to your answer as well.**

Comment: Do you understand what a percentile is? How do you find a percentile given a cdf or a pdf of a continuous distribution? Please update your question with what you understand, what you tried and where you got stuck and we will be happy to guide you further.

Comment: based on your comments about degrees of freedom I’m guessing they are referring to a normal approximation? You be able to compute the mean and standard deviation, and then you can look up how many standard deviations above the mean the 84% quantile of the normal distribution is.

Answer (score 1):

A $\chi_k^2$ distribution is the sum of $k$ IIDs each of mean $1$ and variance $2$, so by the central limit theorem it approximates $N(k,\,2k)$ for large $k$. The $84$th percentile of a Normal variable is $z:=0.9945$ standard deviations above its mean, in this case $54+z\sqrt{108}\approx64.33$. But if you have something more accurate at your disposal, as @kludg did, use it.

Answer (score 0):

Using R, the answer is

```
> qchisq(0.84, 54)
[1] 64.26393
```

Comment: You probably should add some more details to your answer.

Comment: @URL [R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language)) is programming language widely used by statisticians, [qchisq](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/Chisquare) is `R` function which computes quantiles of chi-square distribution.